# Almost a day after publishing app to production

Tags: android, google-play

So it's been a day, almost, 22 hours after I published an app to the play store and I still can't find it when searching it by name. Should I be worried? Min API and Target API are good, and the majority of devices are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Do have a look at this:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en#ts=3056739

This is the play store's explanation to your problem

Comment: Saw that before but to be honest it doesn't help much, only to the point that I have to contact them if the issue persists after 24 hours of published.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it wont take that long. For me it takes couple of hours. Did you search the app by its full name. Usually there are alot of apps in the market and it would be difficult to find the one you just published.

I would also check in the excluded devices section of the playstore. If you are searching this in a device which is in excluded devices, chances are that it wont be shown.

Comment: I did search it by its full name, it is the only app with that name. No luck. Also I have used different devices for the search still no luck, and I'm dead sure the devices are supported.

Comment: check if you are able to find your app by https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your package name>